# Quick Filter in WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

We have a quick filter option in our project, when a user types a text say "Test" in a textbox, it filters out WPF ListView with matching text on 3 columns ( the view has 7 columns). The problem is, the ListView takes little more time to filter the items (say 3 sec). And User have to wait to type "est" unit the filter is completed for "T". This gives a poor experience to User.

The ListView is binded to an `ObservableCollection<SomeItemViewModel>`. I tried to keep the searchable columns in a separate `Dictionary<string, string>`, where the value will be the string concat of the 3 searchable columns. The idea was instead of searching each column and each row from ObservableCollection, I can filter out the matching records from `Dictionary` value and fill the `Collection`. This approach works little better, but still not satisfactory.

Any other approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to not start filtering as soon as the user starts to type. What you could do is, in the OnTextChanged event of a textbox, start a timer with very small Timespan which would not be noticeable to the user(in 100s of milliseconds). Expiration of the timer timespan would trigger an event which would start the filtering. If the text changes before the timer expires, reset the timer.
Filter the text only when the timer expires. This would ensure that the filtering would happen only after the user has completed typing the complete text they want to filter by.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it worked.. I used `DispatcherTimer` instead.

Comment: Glad it worked! Just out of curiosity, did you spend any time in trying to figure out why the filtering was taking up to 3 secs. Do you have a lot of data in your list view?

Comment: :While resetting the Filters on ViewModel side `Refresh` method is getting called, which recreating the view. I refactored that code since my View was binded to an `ObservableCollection`. Secondly, when any filter is applied, the conditions are checked for each row and for each column, instead of only for 3 columns. I refactored using a dictionary. The search operation was reduced to almost 700ms. But still the application could not match with the typing speed of the User. The last resort was to allow the search for whole word instead of each letter.